# How to Write the test case for DAO class with JUNIT5 and mockito in spring boot for the code

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

How to Write the test case for DAO class with JUnit5 and Mockito in spring boot for the code

I am trying to write a test case with JUnit5 and Mockito. How to write the test cases for the below method

DAO class:

```java
public Map<String, Object> addParticipantSubRole(ProductLineParticipantSubRoleDTO subRole, int userId, int buId,int plId) throws RTDataBaseException {
        Map<String, Object> returnMap = new HashMap<>();

        try {

            StoredProcedureQuery query = this.getSession()
                    .createStoredProcedureCall("PKG_QA_PRODUCT_LINE_ADMIN.PROC_ADD_PARTICIP_SUB_ROLES")
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN).setParameter(1, userId)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN).setParameter(2, plId)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .setParameter(3, subRole.getParticipantSubRoleName())
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(4, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .setParameter(4, subRole.getParticipantSubRoleDesc())
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(5, Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(6, Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(7, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter(8, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

            int plParticipantSubRoleId = (Integer) query.getOutputParameterValue(5);
            int returnId = (Integer) query.getOutputParameterValue(6);
            String message = (String) query.getOutputParameterValue(7);

            if (returnId == Constants.SUCCESS_INTEGER_VALUE) {
                returnMap.put(RESULT, plParticipantSubRoleId);
                returnMap.put(RETURN_ID, returnId);
                returnMap.put(RETURN_MESSAGE, message);
            } else {
                returnMap.put(RESULT, subRole);
                returnMap.put(RETURN_ID, returnId);
                returnMap.put(RETURN_MESSAGE, message);
            }

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error(exception.toString());
            throw new RTDataBaseException(userId, "Failed to add PL Sub Role in DB", userId, exception);
        }
        return returnMap;
    }
```

Comment: The simple answer is: don't go down this path. You get a lot of unmaintainable code for little benefit. Test against a db instance: launched in a container for duration of test (you may use testcontainers to help) or in-memory db.

Comment: +1 to the comment above. Use the @DataJpaTest annotation on your test and run your code against an actual database, be it in-memory or a real one.

Answer (score 0):

It makes close to zero sense to do unit testing on the persistance layer. You get a lot of code with close to zero benefit.

Its better to go for an integration test which can look like this ...

```
@DataJpaTest
class MyDaoTest {

  @Autowired private MyDao myDao;

  @Test
  void testMyDao(){
     // Do test setup
     myDay.addParticipantSubRole(/* input parameters */)
    // Do asserts

  }
}
```